# How to install and use httpbuilder plugin in grails

Tags: grails, groovy, httpbuilder

How to install and use httpbuilder plugin in Grails?

Comment: There's no plugin named "httpbuilder". There's a [REST Client](http://www.grails.org/plugin/rest) plugin, though. Was there something unclear about its installation or usage in the [documentation](http://www.grails.org/plugin/rest)? Your question is rather broad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the [REST Client plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/rest):

- Installation:

  ```
  grails install-plugin rest
  ```
- Example:

  ```
  withHttp(uri: "http://www.google.com") {
     def html = get(path : '/search', query : [q:'Groovy'])
     assert html.HEAD.size() == 1
     assert html.BODY.size() == 1
  }
  ```

Comment: How do I do  a post and not get?

Comment: I haven't read the docs or ever used this plugin, but my uneducated guess would be to replace `get` with `post`

Comment: Note that as of 2.3, `install-plugin can no longer be used to install plugins`.  I'm still trying to figure out this one now, and I really miss node/npm :(

Answer (score 28):

Adding httpbuilder 0.5.1 to your application dependencies will cause errors.  In particular, you'll get an error something like this:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving overridden method "org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.getParser()Lorg/xml/sax/Parser;" the class loader (instance of org/codehaus/groovy/grails/cli/support/GrailsRootLoader) of the current class, org/apache/xerces/jaxp/SAXParserImpl, and its superclass loader (instance of <bootloader>), have different Class objects for the type org/xml/sax/Parser used in the signature
```

I think the issue is that httpbuilder is exporting it's compile-time dependencies as runtime dependencies.  An easy workaround is to declare the dependency like this in your `BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    ...
    dependencies {
        runtime('org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.5.1') {
            excludes 'xalan'
            excludes 'xml-apis'
            excludes 'groovy'
        }
    }
}
```

I think you need `mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"` in the repositories section as well.

Comment: You rock ataylor! Solved my afternoon

Comment: Codehaus is now dead. Hence this answer needs updating

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the above step by ataylor but then commented out the block and tested plugin:

```
compile ":rest:0.7"
```

Rest plugin uses http-builder and without having the above dependancy my app still works fine and makes calls through http builder.