# Grails external link params through post

Tags: grails

I need to open an external link, and send some params through post method. I have read that I can use ***redirect()*** to open a link through get method, as the following code:

```
    def get = {
        redirect(url: "http://localhost:8080/test/public/cadastro/dataConfirm.html?" + "username=" + "test")
    }
```

Apparently, redirect only works with get. Is there any command to do this by post method? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46582/response-redirect-with-post-instead-of-get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server-to-server comunication via post in grails can be achieved using the following  [java code](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/Post.html)
. I tested it and works fine in grails. The alternatives are plugins, as @Kelly answered me, and
[Apache Http Components](http://hc.apache.org/)
.

Answer (score 2):

Is your goal to have the user actually redirected to a different site via POST, or POST to a different site and get results back but stay in your site?  If it is actually pushing the user to a different site then Victor's comment is the way to go.

If you are trying to send a POST to a different site, get results and stay on your site look into the [Rest plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/rest) and check out the `withHttp` method.  There is a good example [here](http://coderberry.me/blog/2012/05/07/stupid-simple-post-slash-get-with-groovy-httpbuilder/).

There can be dependency issues when using the Rest plugin.  If you have these check out the answer by [ataylor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190201/ataylor) in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379455/how-to-install-and-use-httpbuilder-plugin-in-grails) stackoverflow post.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Kelly. The second one is what I need. Server-to-server comunication. I'm not a big fan of grails plugins, so I found the java way to do this, but this is a good alternative too. I will answer my own question to let people know the other way.